# Failed to install SingularityCE in WSL - failed to verify certificate

Tags: wsl-2, singularity-container

I want to install Singularity on my WSL, I followed the instructions in [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/blob/v4.0.2/INSTALL.md), I tried with different version however the outcome still the same. I have installed the dependencies and Go correctly but when I run the command to configure and install Singularity:

```
./mconfig make -C builddir sudo make -C builddir install
```

I got this in the output:

```
... ../internal/pkg/runtime/launcher/native/launcher_linux.go:25:2: github.com/sylabs/sif/v2@v2.15.0: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/sylabs/sif/v2/@v/v2.15.0.zip": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority ../internal/pkg/security/selinux/selinux_supported.go:10:8: github.com/opencontainers/selinux@v1.11.0: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/opencontainers/selinux/@v/v1.11.0.zip": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority ../pkg/cmdline/env.go:12:2: github.com/spf13/pflag@v1.0.5: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/spf13/pflag/@v/v1.0.5.zip": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority make: *** [Makefile:181: singularity] Error 1 make: Leaving directory '/home/kdallah/projects/singularity/builddir
```

Am I missing something to be installed or it´s it because I´m using WSL?

I remove old version of Singularity, update CA certificates since it showing that it´s failed to verify certificate, however it´s I still got the same error:

```
failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```